# How should Eclipse RCP target platforms be configured for multiple products?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

In our Eclipse RCP (Kepler with Tycho/Nexus) project we create a custom application with two sub parts. These parts are organized in the features **Planning** and **Production**. They are delivered as three different products: standalone **Planning**, standalone **Production** and a combination of **Planning**-**Production**.

The question is now how the target platform for the builds should look like?
Should the TP be set up per build? Meaning we have four TP for:

- Build TP for creating plugins
- Planning Release TP
- Production Release TP
- Planning-Production Release TP

Or should the TP be looked at like a repository? Meaning there is just one for the whole project and depending on the context the build will get dependencies either from the TP or the local source code.

(To be honest we have the first solution at the moment and my gut tells me it is a bad idea. Although my gut is good enough for me, solution architects tend to ignore such input. I am looking therefore as well for arguments why one or the other solution is better or worse.)

Answer (score 1):

> Or should the TP be looked at like a repository?

That's what we did in a similar situation (though not using Tycho, I don't think this should change things).

For the first option:

1. Primarily, I don't see any point. Since you have a combined release, production and planning dependencies need to be compatible anyway, and you'd certainly want to have same dependencies in development and release.
2. When one of dependencies is updated or removed, you only want to change it in one place (though this may be worked around using features).
3. No need to switch between target platforms to build a release (though this may be irrelevant depending on how exactly you build releases).

Comment: Could you comment why the other solution might be bad?